# How to keep object/video tag out of the HTML untill page has fully loaded?

Tags: html

I have made a page full of embed videos from youtube and vimeo. And the load time is horrific! It makes my laptop completely freeze until they have all been properly loaded.

I have seen in another article that the way to do it is to keep the object or video tag out of the HTML and then add it after page has loaded. I have since been trying to work out how to do this but no luck!

I have also seen on other websites that they have a loading gif behind the tag until the video is fully.

Any advice on how to do either of these or another method would be great!

**some embed video code:**

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/57564747" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into using javascript to add the items to the page when the page's onload event fires?

Comment: Also, look into any preloading the videos are doing. For instance with the video tag there is a preload attribute that can be set to none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to load them only on demand.

Put a dummy picture where a video will be. If the picture is clicked, load the content via jQuery or JS.

```
<div id='video-anchor'>
    <img id='dummy' src='http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/403/127/403127670_960.jpg' alt='' />
</div>


$('#dummy').click(function() {
    $('#video-anchor').html(
         '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/57564747" 
          width="500" 
          height="281" 
          frameborder="0" 
          webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
    ');
});
```

You can get the images that vimeo uses. They are set as background-image for the `div.vimeo_holder`.

Comment: Wow thanks great idea. I will get back to you when I have tried it! How should I get the dummy picture? just print screen?

Comment: Thanks! how did you do that? (It will also get rid of the annoying vimeo staff pick logo :) )

Comment: In Chrome: right click on the background, inspect element, strg+f 'vimeo_holder'

Comment: Great cheers! dreamweaver says there is a syntax error in your code and I have no idea why?

Comment: probably the linebreaks in the iframe? I wanted to increase readability but it might cause problems.

Comment: Sorry I am pretty new to this. What can I do to improve?

Comment: write the `iframe` tag in a single line. Don't break it up into multiple lines. If this doesn't help. Tell me what the error says.

Comment: This is a long shot. But you know when you click on the image you have to wait for a bit for the video to load. Is there anyway that you know of to put a loading gif during that period?

Comment: Set it as the background image for the div you fill with the video. :)

Comment: You are probably the best person ever.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to make your page full of thumbnail image screenshots of your various videos.  And when someone clicks on a specific screenshot image, activate a pop-up window that displays that specific video.  This puts less stress on your load time, and you can do this for a lot of videos within a given page.